# Working with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am totally new to python, so my question may seem stupid. 
Basically I need to ask the user to determine a working directory, create a folder in that address, and then run the rest of script. 
I know how to get the directory, but I do not know how to use it in my script.

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
directory= tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
```

and I need to create a folder in that address, so I try this:

```
os.mkdir (directory/map)
```

But I got error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\run_aermap_script_c - train.py", line 39, in <module>
    os.mkdir (directory/map_C)
NameError: name 'map_C' is not defined
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Best,

Comment: Could you add the error message you get to the question, please?

Comment: If there is but one single thing you learn from the experience of posting this question, please let it be that you must **always provide the error message** when asking for help.

Comment: @cjrh And preferably the **full traceback** in the case of a python exception.

Comment: Here is the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\run_aermap_script_c - train.py", line 39, in <module>
    os.mkdir (directory/map_C)
NameError: name 'map_C' is not defined

Comment: `os.mkdir` takes a `string` so `directory/map_C` needs to be a string or variables containing strings combined eg. `'hello' + 'world'` = `'helloword'`

Comment: @Steven Summers Thank you so Much. That really helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NameError: name X is not defined` occurs when Python can't find X as a variable name. So that tells you that Python is looking for a *variable* named X. However, you don't define X as a variable (at least in the code you posted). You want X to be part of a path name, which should be a string. I'd suggest you read up on Python string behavior and how to build longer strings from shorter ones.

Answer (score 0):

`askdirectory()` returns the full path of an existing directory.  If you want to create a new directory/folder named 'map-C` within that existing directory, then use

```
os.mkdir(os.path.join(directory, 'map-C'))
```

"If the directory already exists, OSError is raised." ([mkdir doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir))